GitHub CodeSpace for all Branches of Repository
I need to create a GitHub Codespace where I can check out branches within the repo from within the Browser-based VS studio. So basically, I need the whole repo to be available from my Codepace. Is this possible please?

I'll answer my own question. When you make a CodeSpace, it says "create CodeSpace on main." I thought this would mean just that branch would be available. However, there is a small icon in the status bar of VS studio which allows you to access the other branches. The wording of the create message seems misleading to me, but at least I can access the other branches.
